How to JSON decode an empty object
I'm decoding the response from an API and that works when I have the expected data.
But the server often responds with {} or {}\n, an empty object. It is expected.
I would like to capture these responses before trying to decode the expected data.
I have resorted to the following scheme, but I feel there should be a more principled way to decode an empty json object.
    let empty1 = "{}".data(using: .utf8)!
    let empty2 = "{}\n".data(using: .utf8)!

    let (data, response) = try await URLSession.shared.data(for: request)
    if data == empty1 || data == empty2 {
        print("empty json response")
        return nil
    }

    // what I would like to do
    let decoded = try JSONDecoder().decode(xxxx, from: data)  // what to decode here
    
    // how to test for emptyness

I can also compare the String representation of the data, but that is just the same as my current scheme.

The question is not "is it empty?". It should be "is it my expected type?".

It is expected. I could make my response struct with all optional properties,
but I did not want to do that. The server sends an empty object or one with data in it.
These responses have different meaning. I thought there would be a simple way to decode an empty json object.

I assume you want the JSONDecoder().decode call to throw an error when the data is not empty. You can do this by

creating a custom coding key that can represent any key in JSON
getting a keyed decoding container keyed by the above key
checking if the decoding container contains any keys - if it does, the JSON is not empty.

struct EmptyJSON: Decodable {
    struct AnyKey: CodingKey {
        var stringValue: String
        
        init?(stringValue: String) {
            self.stringValue = stringValue
        }
        
        var intValue: Int?
        
        init?(intValue: Int) {
            self.intValue = intValue
            self.stringValue = "\(intValue)"
        }
        
    }
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: AnyKey.self)
        if !container.allKeys.isEmpty {
            throw CustomDecodingError.shouldBeEmpty
        }
    }

    enum CustomDecodingError: Error {
        case shouldBeEmpty
    }
}

Then you can do:
if let decoded = try? JSONDecoder().decode(EmptyJSON.self, from: data) {
    // JSON is empty
} else {
    // JSON is not empty
}

This will treat JSON arrays as "empty" too. You can catch the specific error to have more control
do {
    try JSONDecoder().decode(EmptyJSON.self, from: data)
    // empty object
} catch EmptyJSON.CustomDecodingError.shouldBeEmpty {
    // non-empty object
} catch {
    // something else, e.g. array (both empty and non-empty), string, number
}


Thank you for your answer, it gave me an idea to use just struct EmptyJSON: Decodable { }
and that works for me.

@kissy struct EmptyJSON: Decodable { } would be successfully decoded even when the JSON is not empty.

yes you're right, I didn't consider that.

Your answer helped me focus and shows an alternative way using a struct EmptyJSON.
It is somewhat convoluted, I could use a simple
struct EmptyJSON: Decodable { let empty: String? }
or make all properties of my real struct optionals.
